# 10-Year SDET Looking to Pivot to ML - Seeking Advice and Insights

Tags: machine-learning, career

I'm on a journey to pivot my 10-year career as an SDET to the fascinating world of Machine Learning. I'm currently upskilling and diving into coding projects to get hands-on experience in ML. But what I really need insights on is the practicality of this transition in today's job market.

I'm curious about the challenges I might face and the areas I should prioritize in my learning. How do job prospects look for someone transitioning from software testing to ML? What skills are most in-demand? Are there specific industry sectors or project types I should focus on?

I'm fully committed to putting in the necessary work, no matter how challenging it may be. Any guidance, personal experiences, or advice on making this transition successful would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help and insights!